# Receiving error 'The function expression is invalid' for InsertData ampscript function

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using a Marketing Cloud Cloud Page to sync contact/lead records from a Data Extension to corresponding Sales Cloud Campaigns (as campaign members). This part is working well. However I'm receiving an error when I try to write information into a Data Extension by using the InsertData function. I'm getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38kHd.png) when I add the InsertData function into my code.

Here is my code for InsertData:

```
InsertData('SubscriptionSyncLog',
'SyncTime', @localTime, 
'UniqueId', @uniqueId,
'LookupValue', @rowValue, 
'SubscriptionId', @subscriptionId, 
'CampaignId', @campaignId, 
'Message', @outcome
)
```

Here is the entire cloud page code:

```
<!---------------------DEBUGGING SCRIPT START--------------------->

<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core","1"); 
try {
</script>

<!---------------------------AMPSCRIPT---------------------------->

%%[

/*---------------------------SYNC RECORDS ISSUBSCRIBED = TRUE---------------------------*/

/**************SC CAMPAIGN, DE AND ROWS TO LOOK UP*******************/
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @i, @subCentreDE, @rowValue, @columnValue, @campaignMemberId, @localTime

set @subCentreDE = "ChosenSubscription" /* DE to look for */
set @columnValue = "IsSubscribed" /* DE column to look for */
set @rowValue = "True" /* DE row value to look for */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@subCentreDE,3000,"Email Asc",@columnValue,@rowValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) /* Count the total rows found */

output(concat("<br>Row,Outcome,CampaignMemberId,Email,UniqueId,Record Type,SubscriptionId,CampaignId,IsSubscribed,Date Synced"))

/*******************CHECK IF ROWS ARE FOUND***************************/

if @rowCount > 0 then 
    
  /*************************ROWS FOUND***********************************/
  /*****ADD EACH RECORD FROM THE DE TO THE SC CAMPAIGN IF NOT FOUND******/
  
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

var @email, @uniqueId, @idField, @campaignMemberRow, @campaignMemberRows, @subscriptionId, @campaignId, @outcome
set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
set @email = field(@row,"email")
set @uniqueId = field(@row,"uniqueId")
set @subscriptionId = field(@row,"subscriptionId")

/***************MAP SUBSCRIPTION ID TO SC CAMPAIGN ID******************/

set @rows2 = LookupRows('Subscription','SubscriptionId',@subscriptionId)
set @rowCount2 = rowcount(@rows2) /* Count the total rows found */

if @rowCount > 0 then
    
    set @row2 = row(@rows2, 1)
    set @campaignId = field(@row2,"CampaignId")

endif

if not empty(@uniqueId) then

  /************IDENTIFY IF THE RECORD IS A CONTACT OR LEAD***************/
    if Substring(@uniqueId, 1,3) == "00Q" then

        set @idField = "LeadId"

        elseif Substring(@uniqueId, 1,3) == "003" then

        set @idField = "ContactId"

        else

        set @idField = "invalid"
        output(concat("<br>Invalid @uniqueId: ", @uniqueId)) 
        
    endif
 
    /*********CHECK IF THE UNIQUE ID AND CAMPAIGN ID IS VALID************/
    
    set @outcome = "Invalid uniqueId or no campaignId mapped to subscription. Check the DE named: Subscription"

    if @idField != "invalid" and (not empty(@campaignId)) then

        /******************SEARCH FOR RECORD IN CAMPAIGN*********************/
        var @campaignMemberStatus
        set @campaignMemberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('CampaignMember', "Id, Status", 'CampaignId', '=', @campaignId, @idField, "=", @uniqueId)
        
        /***********************CHECK IF RECORD FOUND**************************/
        if RowCount(@campaignMemberRows) == 0 then
        
            /****************RECORD NOT FOUND, ADD TO CAMPAIGN*******************/
            set @campaignMemberId = CreateSalesforceObject(
            'CampaignMember', 3,
            'CampaignId', @campaignId,
            @idField, @uniqueId,
            'Status','Subscribed'
            )
            
            set @localTime = DateAdd(NOW(), 19, "H")
            set @outcome = "Added campaign member with status: Subscribed"
        
            elseif RowCount(@campaignMemberRows) > 0 then

            /*************RECORD FOUND, CHECK CAMPAIGN MEMBER STATUS*************/
            set @campaignMemberRow = Row(@campaignMemberRows, 1)
            set @campaignMemberId = Field(@campaignMemberRow, "Id")
            set @campaignMemberStatus = Field(@campaignMemberRow, "Status")

            if @campaignMemberStatus != "Subscribed" then
                
                /*************UPDATE CAMPAIGN MEMBER STATUS TO SUBSCRIBED************/
                UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember', @campaignMemberId, 'Status', 'Subscribed')
                
                set @localTime = DateAdd(NOW(), 19, "H")*/
                set @outcome = "Updated campaign member with status: Subscribed" 

                else
                
                /**************CAMPAIGN MEMBER STATUS ALREADY SUBSCRIBED*************/
                set @localTime = DateAdd(NOW(), 19, "H")
                set @outcome = "Skipped - campaign member up to date"

            endif
           
        endif

    endif

endif   

/***************WRITE TO PROCESS LOGGING DATA EXTENSION**************/
InsertData('SubscriptionSyncLog',
'SyncTime', @localTime, 
'UniqueId', @uniqueId,
'LookupValue', @rowValue, 
'SubscriptionId', @subscriptionId, 
'CampaignId', @campaignId, 
'Message', @outcome
)

]%%

<!------------------------DEBUGGING VALUES------------------------>

<br>%%=v(@i)=%%,%%=v(@outcome)=%%,%%=v(@campaignMemberId)=%%,%%=v(@email)=%%,%%=v(@uniqueId)=%%,%%=v(@idField)=%%,%%=v(@subscriptionId)=%%,%%=v(@campaignId)=%%,%%=v(@rowValue)=%%,%%=v(@localTime)=%%

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%


<!----------------------DEBUGGING SCRIPT END---------------------->

<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
 Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Here are screenshots of the [fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZmwE.png) and [name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOH8c.png) of the Data Extension I'm writing data to.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Go Ahead and Publish the Page. The error is only in the preview.

[Reference](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003yCfQAI&title=cloudpages-preview-shows-error-with-certain-ampscript-or-ssjs-functions)